# How to remove all elements except last one with same document.querySelectorAll(".someClass") using only javascript without jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

My query is simple :

How to remove all elements except last one with same `document.querySelectorAll(".someClass")` using only javascript without jQuery.

I can do it with jQuery with only one line like this:

```js
$('.someClass').not(':last(2)').remove();
```

But I want to do it with pure JavaScript; how can I do that?
Any idea?

I tried this code :

```js
var lists = document.querySelectorAll(".someClass");
for(var i = 1; i < lists.length; i++) {
  lists[i].parentElement.removeChild(lists[i]);
}
```

But it removes all elements except the first one. But I want to keep the last one.

Comment: "pure JavaScript:" => "with the [DOM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model)" (it's pure JavaScript either way). (Useful to know that for searching.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will remove all but the last element from your nodeList

EDIT:

```js
const elems = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(".someClass"))
elems.pop()
elems.map(node => node.parentNode.removeChild(node))
```

Comment: BUT I WANT TO KEEP LAST ELEMENT AND REMOVE ALL OTHER

Comment: am getting this error:

Uncaught TypeError: nodeToRemove.map is not a function

Comment: Sorry, I edited again. I tried the code it works

Comment: Thanks a Lot, Caro

Answer (score 2):

Stop just before the last one:

```
var lists = document.querySelectorAll(".someClass");
for(var i = 1; i < lists.length - 1; i++) {
//                             ^^^^−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−
    lists[i].parentElement.removeChild(lists[i]);
}
```

Or alternatively, in all vaguely-modern browsers:

```
const lists = Array.prototype.slice.call(
    document.querySelectorAll(".someClass"),
    0, -1
);
for (const list of lists) {
    list.remove();
}
```

That uses the `slice` method from `Array.prototype` to grab all of the entries from the `NodeList` returned by `querySelectorAll` except the last one, then loops over that result removing those elements.

Answer (score 2):

```
var lists = document.querySelectorAll(".someClass");
for(var i = 0; i < lists.length -1; i++) {
  lists[i].parentElement.removeChild(lists[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try using this.

```
var lists = document.querySelectorAll(".someClass");
for(var i = 1; i < lists.length; i++) {
  if (i !== lists.length - 1) lists[i].parentElement.removeChild(lists[i]);
}
```

You can perform the above action on every item in the array except for the last one (the last index is `array.length - 1` since the first index is `0`.

Answer (score 2):

You were close:

```js
let endIndex = 1 // how many you want to delete
var lists = document.querySelectorAll(".someClass");
for(var i = 0; i < lists.length - 1 - endIndex; i++) {
  lists[i].parentElement.removeChild(lists[i]);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try with this:

```
$("#parent_id").children(":not(#id_n)").remove();
```